# When i try to dev-deploy for any contract i get `BadRequestError`

Tags: nearprotocol

I cloned https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/sample--thanks and when I try to run the `dev-deploy` I am getting the below error. I am getting the same error for some other contracts too.

How can I fix this error?

```
BadRequestError: Error: nonce retries exceeded for transaction. This usually means there are too many parallel requests with the same access key.
```

Edit: Under the same conditions this error happens occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: There is a limit on the number of accounts that can be created per second using `dev-deploy`, and when there is high demand, this error may occur. Retrying can help getting your account deployed.

---

When you run `dev-deploy` a new account is created for you in NEAR Testnet, by [`testnet`](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/accounts/testnet) account. To execute a deploy tx one of the Full Access Keys associated with this account is used.

The problem is that each key, has a nonce associated with it, and each tx executed with a key should have a nonce bigger than the previous nonce used for a tx. This means that you can't execute two transactions in parallel using the same nonce with the same key.

When several users try to creates accounts using `dev-deploy` on NEAR Testnet at the same time, the same nonce is used for different tx, and only the first one to be processed is included on chain.