# Transaction status is `not started` on testnet explorer

Tags: nearprotocol

After I deploy a contract to "testnet" I click the explorer link on the terminal for the transaction but the status of the transaction on the explorer was `not started`.

It is almost one and half hour and it still has the status `not started`.

here is the transaction [link](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/6dmeQJh65cVWYcPQKTKDT2dnRdeRKhHEuxej8GsZ2nWU)

Update: after a while the transaction turned `Succeeded`

Comment: Has the transaction actually succeeded? Can you attach a screenshot of your terminal where you deployed the contract?

Comment: is this transaction related to your other post re: dev-deploy? or a different one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68016013/2836874

Comment: it is related to the older post.  I also did another dev-deploy for the same contract and got the same `not started` transaction status on explorer for that as well.

- [this](https://gist.github.com/ozanisgor/10224e53310f483852191232f0bd8f91) is the gist of what I have on my terminal:
- and the new transaction on explorer [here](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/C7gvjnMa7PtBHWnEjCkEuw36eRs9MFtuH5dnUfQKaqyW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was an incident on Explorer, and now it is resolved, and the link is pointing to the correct transaction details page, and the transaction was successfully executed.